# Sampling from hypergeometric distribution

Tags: r, sampling, hypergeometric-distribution

Suppose there are 1 million balls in the urn. And 1% of those are red, the rest are black. I sample 1000 balls from the urn, and I want to know what's the cumulative probability of getting at least 10 red balls (i.e. prevalence of 1%). I use the `phyper` function in R.

```
1 - phyper(9, 0.01*100000000, 0.99*100000000, 1000)
```

Which returns a probability of 0.5427. Now suppose I iterate the sample size from 200 to 1000 and then plot it.

```
plot(sapply(seq(200, 1000, 100), function(n){1-phyper(0.01*n-1, 0.01*1E6, 0.99*1E6, n)}), ylab = "Probability of Detecting 10% Prevalence")
```

[image]

My question is, why does the probability decrease as sample size increases? Is it because in the formula for the hypergeometric PDF, as the sample size increases, the denominator increases, therefore the entire probability decreases?

Comment: Please check that your code makes sense.  In particular, `0.01*n-1` is almost never an integer in your calculations. The manual states this value is "the number of white balls drawn without replacement from an urn which contains both black and white balls," so how can it be non-integral?

Comment: @whuber, Ah yes, thank you. I'll update my original post.

Comment: Thank you (+1).  As a hint, continue your plot out to very large sample sizes. You will find it reaches a limit, *and then increases*.